# Validating whether $_REQUEST contents is an int

Tags: php, ajax

I am trying to do a basic operation: to check whether string is a number.

This does not work:

```
$qty = $_REQUEST[qty];
if (is_int($qty) == FALSE) {
  echo "error";
} else {
  echo "ok";
}
```

This one does:

```
$qty = 1;
if (is_int($qty) == FALSE) {
  echo "error";
} else {
  echo "ok";
}
```

`$_REQUEST[qty]` is posted with AJAX request `($.post). $_REQUEST[qty]` is NOT empty and contains only number (1).

`is_numeric()` is not going to work, since it treats `1e4` as a number.

Comment: Do you mean `$qty = $_REQUEST['qty']` (with quotes) ...?

Comment: Does not matter. Always works with or without quotes in any script.

Comment: @Radio yes, it works, but also raises a `NOTICE` level error (_PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant foo - assumed 'foo'_). Omitting the quotes PHP assumes you mean the same with quotes. That one time when you actually have a constant defined with the same name, you'll be pulling hairs for a long time before catching it. Always use quotes.

Comment: I never use same names for constants and post vars. That is stupid to begin with. What else?

Comment: No easy solution you gave me.
Most votes unreasonably went to Rodik, which did not read my question to begin with.
Thanks anyways.

I decided to go with preg_match().

    if (!preg_match("/^[0-9]+$/", $_REQUEST[qty])) {}

Comment: @Radio It is a *SYNTAX ERROR*. Good enough? The PHP interpreter's permissive attitude let's you get away with it, but besides generating an *ERROR* (which is expensive) it generates *UNNECESSARY* file IO *EVERY TIME*, since it's likely being logged. See the manual entry for `Array` for further reading: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.donts

Answer (score 7, accepted):

is_int will only return true if the variable is of integer type.
if you are trying to test if the variable contains a string which represents a number,
use:

```
is_numeric("1");
```

source: http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-int.php

**EDIT:**

use ctype_digit() to check for every character in the string if it's a number to rule out "1e4"

Comment: Like I said is_numeric() is not going to work, see the reason.

Comment: OP specifically mentions that `is_numeric()` is not a solution for him since it also accepts scientific notation and floating point numbers...

Comment: Also, there might be a way to do this via Regex.
i suck at regex, but this might have the answer: http://davidwalsh.name/php-validatie-numeric-digits

Comment: @Rodik: No need for regex, no need for ctype_digit, [it's much easier](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8701722/367456).

Answer (score 4):

If you want to check for the presence of digits only, you can use [ctype_digit](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-digit.php) .

Answer (score 2):

try "is_numeric()" instead of "is_int"...

i think that u r getting a String from your Request...
and is_int really checks wether a given object is a integer... But it isn't -> it's a String.

is_numeric just checks, wether a object is convertable into an integer. If so, it returns true, otherwise false...

```
$qty = $_REQUEST[qty];
if (is_numeric($qty) == FALSE) {
  echo "error";
} else {
  echo "ok";
}
```

PS: Use $_POST[] or $_GET[] insetead of $_REQUEST[] ;)

Comment: is_numeric() treats values like "1e4" as TRUE. I need to check for numbers ONLY. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php

Answer (score 2):

You mention you cannot use `is_numeric` because it treats `1e4` as a number. Well, `1e4` is a number. Specifically `1 * 10^4`.

You could use `is_int(intval($_REQUEST['qty']))`, but as `intval` always returns an int (0 on failure or empty input) you run the risk of false positives. However, combined with `is_numeric` or `filter_var` you should be on pretty solid ground.

Comment: You gotta be kidding me? No PHP operator to find out if string is just a number? =))

Comment: @Radio if you mean _a string consisting solely of digits_, the answer is `ctype_digit` as @Srisa mentions in his answer, or a regex.

Answer (score 2):

Do a [not-identical comparison<sup>*­Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) while using the string and integer cast:

```
if ($qty !== (string)(int)$qty) {
  echo "error";
} else {
  echo "ok";
}
```

This is basically literal: As all incoming variables are strings, you can't check them being an integer, unless you cast them to an integer and then back to string. Wrap it into a function if it's to hard to grasp in inline code what it does:

```
/**
 * string is integer value?
 *
 * @return bool
 */
function is_int_string($string)
{
  return $string === (string)(int)$string;
}

$qty = $_REQUEST[qty];
if (is_int_string($qty) == FALSE) {
  echo "error";
} else {
  echo "ok";
}
```

HTTP is a text protocol, so there is only string in the beginning.

Comment: (int)$qty will treat any alpha character as INT. Does not work.

Comment: @Radion: Now I understood what you mean, I slightly edited the answer to deal with that, it's the same principle, cast and compare.

Comment: Sounds like solution, but not as simple as mine: if (!preg_match("/^[0-9]+$/", $_REQUEST[qty])) {}

Comment: Seriously, using regex for that? Not that it's not possible, but two casts versus a function call plus a regex compilation and execution, I would say, that's a bit over the head. But do what pleases you ;)

Comment: Who cares about script execution time these days? It's just about ease of coding. One line looks better than 3. =)

Comment: Uhm, you should read the answer, it is a one-liner. But anyway, you've shown your commitment to your solution which is fine as you need to deal with it in the end anyway. I was merely concerned that you understand how things work and that the suggestion I made is technically correct. There is often more than one solution to a problem.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, all $_REQUEST (as well as $_GET, $_POST, etc) values are always **strings**.

When `$qty` is `$_REQUEST[qty]` it's an string, not an integer. When `$qty` is `1`, it's already an integer.

Use `intval` function to convert it to an integer. But as you say, you only want to find out whether it's an integer or not, so use `floatval` to convert it, then check if they are equal:

```
if (intval($qty) == floatval($qty)) {
     echo "Ok!";
} else {
     echo "error";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I decided to go with preg_match().

```
if (!preg_match("/^[0-9]+$/", $_REQUEST[qty])) {}
```